# Windows is delaying release of a key, and sometime the key get stuck forever

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, autohotkey

I am experiencing this issue from quite sometime. Keys get stuck (not physically) until I press them again. Sometime for 1-2 seconds, sometime forever.

Here is one the example I have

```
A2  01D     d   0.39    LControl        
A0  02A     d   0.02    LShift          
52  013 #   d   0.28    r               
52  013     u   0.11    r               
52  013 #   d   0.11    r               
52  013     u   0.09    r               
52  013 #   d   0.09    r               
52  013     u   0.11    r               
52  013 #   d   0.09    r               
52  013     u   0.14    r                       
09  00F #   d   0.33    Tab             
09  00F     u   0.17    Tab             
09  00F #   d   0.30    Tab             
09  00F     u   0.11    Tab                     
09  00F #   d   0.26    Tab             
A0  02A     u   0.13    LShift          
09  00F     u   0.02    Tab             
09  00F #   d   0.86    Tab             
09  00F     u   0.17    Tab
```

In this example, I pressed Ctrl+Shift+R several times very quickly, and then release <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> in my browser.

Unfortunately the key doesn't get released until later causing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to be sent briefly and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

What is causing this issue?

Note:

- There are even more complex case where I have to press Win key or <kbd>Fn</kbd> key or Right Shift key for no reason to fix it. (I normally never ever use Right Shift key so having to use it to fix the sticky key issue seems pretty weird)
- Sticky Key, Toggle Key, Filter keys are all disabled.
- This example is generated in AutoHotkey. I even exited program, but was still able to reproduce the issue.

**Update:**

I tried using the same keyboard in safe mode and later on a fresh Ubuntu machine on a USB flash drive. Looks like I need a new keyboard.

Comment: You could have dying hardware. Have you tried another keyboard to see if that produces the same result?

Comment: @LPChip Yes. You are right. I tried some more things. Tl;dr; is that I need a new keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using it in Safe mode as well as with a fresh Ubuntu instance on a USB flash device, and the issue persisted.

Looks like I need a new keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a wireless keyboard of any sort, make sure the receiver is <2ft away and not obstructed, and that the keyboard batteries are good, if it has batteries. If it's a wired keyboard you should probably just replace it.

Comment: Yes unfortunately it's internal keyboard.